24.04 locks up with DejaDup and some Settings
Installed Ubuntu 24.04 (Noble Numbat).   After installation  noted locked up when going to some Settings – Display for one: overlay would flicker, mostly disappear, lock up.  Found suggestion to go back to X11 due to incompatibility between Wayland and (some) Nvidia video cards.  Thought fixed the problem until today: when configuring Deja Dup (first time) freezes system ==> clock stops advancing but can usually REISUB out (though shuts off rather than reboots – I am not -O’ing).
Fiddling after to change Desktop background: that also freezes the system!
Found this suggestion: apt-get reinstall gnome-remote-desktop    (and then reboot).  That seems to have fixed the Change Desktop problem but DejaDup still locks up almost immediately.
System specs:
CPU:    AMD FX-8300
MB: ASUS M51BC
RAM:    2x 8 GB (16 total, MB will accept max 32)  inxi reports as DDR3
OS: 24.01 Noble Numbat  – updated during today’s fiddlings
Linux version 6.8.0-50-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-020) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.3.0-6ubuntu2~24.04) 13.3.0, GNU ld (GNU>
Stuff that looks suspicious to me (but what it means I haven’t a clue):
Extracted from Syslog (and I forgot to note times when I did something – sorry!)
2024-12-14T17:14:02.488773-06:00 ThermalTake upowerd[1863]: g_udev_device_get_sysfs_path: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
2024-12-14T17:14:02.489069-06:00 ThermalTake upowerd[1863]: g_udev_client_query_by_sysfs_path: assertion 'sysfs_path != NULL' failed
Extracted from journalctl – boot that failed:
Dec 14 17:11:09 ThermalTake dbus-daemon[1458]: [session uid=1000 pid=1458] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.DejaDup'
Dec 14 17:11:12 ThermalTake kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: trapped write at 00201a4a00 on channel 6 [3f63c000 deja-dup[3225]] engine 00 [PGRAPH] client 0b [PROP] subclient 09 [LOCAL] reason 00000002 [PAGE_NOT_PRESENT]
Dec 14 17:11:13 ThermalTake kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: TRAP_PROP - TP 0 - Unknown CUDA fault at address 00201a1000
Dec 14 17:11:12 ThermalTake gnome-shell[1728]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x1c00021
Dec 14 17:11:12 ThermalTake gnome-shell[1728]: Can't update stage views actor unnamed [MetaWindowActorX11] is on because it needs an allocation.
So suggestions please on how to get the system to behave.
Barry
